# Is it correct to say "all at no avail" in a sentence? or must I say "all to no avail"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, usage

Is it correct to say "all at no avail" in a sentence? or must I say "all to no avail"?

Comment: The standard idiom is _to no avail_.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition **to** is used to express motion or direction towards something, including towards an end result.

The preposition **at** is used to indicate a location or condition.

The expression *to no avail* means that something *led to, or resulted in* no profit, gain or advantage. The preposition "to" is correctly used to indicate a journey towards an end result. It wouldn't make any sense with "at", and even if you could contrive a scenario where you *could* say it, it isn't an idiom.

Comment: So the correct thing to say would be “I made so many attempts to  beat this game but all to no avail.” Not “all at no avail...”

Comment: @spacenet One doesn't **beat** a game. One beats an opponent / team but **wins** a game.

Comment: @RonaldSole Not necessarily - as computer "games" have an AI they are both a game and an opponent. It is widely accepted that you can "beat" a computer game.

Comment: @spacenet Yes, you made multiple attempts and those attempts led to no victory. See my reply to RonaldSole about your use of the term 'beat' - you win a game, but beat an opponent. If you're talking about a computer game or similar then your sentence is correct, otherwise adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Astralbee Little wonder that Freecell so often gets the better of me!